# C# select values of a property from a list inside a list

Tags: c#, list

I have following objects

```
class A
{
    public List<B> listB { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

and in my application I have a scenario like below..

```
public void main()
{    
    var lstA = new List<A>();

    var lstA = new List<A>();

    var a1 = new A();
    a1.listB = new List<B> 
    { 
        new B() { id = 1 },
        new B() { id = 2 }
    };
    lstA.Add(a1);

    a1 = new A();
    a1.listB = new List<B> 
    { 
        new B() { id = 3 },
        new B() { id = 4 }
    };
    lstA.Add(a1);
}
```

And I need to select all id's of **B** objects from **lstA**

Here is what I've tried so far

```
var ids = lst.Select(x=>x.listB.Select(y=>y.id)).ToList();
```

But It gives me a compilation error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, use `SelectMany`

```
var ids = lst.SelectMany(x=>x.listB.Select(y=>y.id)).ToList();
```

Check your [`Working Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dSAN3r)

Comment: Casting down vote without leaving comment will not help anybody, please comment. We can always improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `SelectMany` which flattens the lists:

```
var ids = lst.SelectMany(x => x.listB.Select(y => y.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i did and it works perfectly
All i did was make the classes public and when you initialise `List<B>`, you add `new List<B>` because even though intellisense doesn't show you any error, when you run the application, you get object not referenced error

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lstA = new List<A>();

        var a1 = new A()
        {
            listB = new List<B>()
            {
                new B
                {
                    id = 3
                },
                new B
                {
                    id = 5
                }
            }
        };
        var a2 = new A()
        {
            listB = new List<B>()
            {
                new B
                {
                    id = 1
                },
                new B
                {
                    id = 8
                }
            }
        };

        lstA.Add(a1);
        lstA.Add(a2);
        var ids = lstA.SelectMany(r => r.listB.Select(x => x.id));
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class A
{
    public List<B> listB { get; set; }

}

public class B
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the classes being `public` or any other. However you mention the same as Hari and me also suggested in our answers namely to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`. This is what solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this to ignore duplicate id

```
var ids = lstA.SelectMany(x => x.listB.Select(y => y.id)).Distinct().ToList();
```